# uwsgi nginx lua, I've only seen 500 Server Errors.  uwsgi log only re spawns

Tags: lua, nginx, uwsgi

Ok here is what I have already tried, on the nginx

```
#location ~ \.lua$ {
#    include uwsgi_params;
#    uwsgi_modifier1 6;
#    uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/luajit/socket;
#}


#location ~ / {
#                include uwsgi_params;
#                uwsgi_param UWSGI_FILE $request_filename;
#                uwsgi_param UWSGI_TOUCH_RELOAD $request_filename;
#                uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $uri;
#                uwsgi_modifier1 9;
#                if (-f $request_filename) {
#                 uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/luajit/socket;
#
#                }
#        }
#location ~ \.cgi$ {
#    include fastcgi_params;
#    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/luajit/socket;
#    uwsgi_modifier1 9;
#
#}

#location ~ / {
#                include uwsgi_params;
#                uwsgi_param UWSGI_FILE test.cgi;
#                uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME test.cgi;
#                uwsgi_modifier1 9;
#3uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/luajit/socket;
#        }
```

here is my uwsgi, config

default.xml

```
<uwsgi>
    <autoload>true</autoload>
    <master>true</master>
    <threads>25</threads>
    <workers>2</workers>
    <no-orphans>true</no-orphans>
    <pidfile>/var/run/uwsgi/%n/pid</pidfile>
    <socket>/var/run/uwsgi/%n/socket</socket>
    <chmod-socket>660</chmod-socket>
    <log-date>true</log-date>
    <uid>www-data</uid>
    <gid>www-data</gid>
</uwsgi>
```

luajit.xml

```
<uwsgi>
    <plugins>luajit</plugins>
    <protocol>uwsgi</protocol>
</uwsgi>
```

I have tried doing this so many way, I have even lost count.  I couldn't even get anything doing regular cgi.  I prefer to do it like this,

test.lua > wsapi > luajit plugin uwsgi server > uwsgi protocol > nginx

But really at this point, i would like uwsgi work at all.  I am running this on Ubuntu, so it is the debianized modular version of uwsgi.

can i run legacy cgi style scripts like this?  what is wsapi.cgi?  does it wrap lua cgi as wsapi, or lua wsapi as cgi.

I'm so lost, been at this for almost a week.

Would really appreciate any help.  Even just to push me in the correct direction.
I was unable to find any documentation, or write-ups. which is why I'm posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the official doc: http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Lua

You should build latest versions (better going with 1.0 branch) as debian packages does not containes latest lua patches.

Regarding cgi, nginx does not support it, and the plugin in uWSGI is still incomplete.